# Pymongo cursor not looping

Tags: python, pymongo

This works-

```
cursor = collection.find(query).limit(10678)
for doc in cursor: print "entered loop"
```

This doesn't-

```
cursor = collection.find(query).limit(10679)
for doc in cursor: print "entered loop"
```

It just doesn't enter the loop. Ofcourse this upper-limit-number is different for different collections, which may be because of difference in size of each doc. So is there any size limitation for cursors in pymongo ?
Any clues?

Comment: Have you checked the `count()` of the cursor? Does it actually point to any data?

Comment: yes, i did check the count. It is as expected. However, im not able to do `cursor.next()` or `for doc in cursor` Should i use `batchsize` to limit the size? Any link to batch-size example?

Comment: And what does `cursor.next()` do? Is any error raised?

Comment: doesn't raise anything, the python script just stops executing. Dead stop, without any message. Thats what drove me to find out the exact no of docs tolerated by the for loop

Comment: Have you tried executing the query in the mongo shell directly (to find whether it is a problem in PyMongo or MongoDB itself)?