# Looping over Pymongo cursor returns bson.errors.InvalidBSON error after some iterations

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying making a simple query with pymongo and looping over the results.

This is the code I'm using:

```
data = []
tam = db.my_collection.find({'timestamp': {'$gte': start, '$lte':end}}).count()
for i,d in enumerate(table.find({'timestamp': {'$gte': start, '$lte':end}}):
    print('%s of %s' % (i,tam))
    data.append(d)
```

start and end variables are datetime python objects. Everything runs fine until I get the following output:

```
2987 of 12848
2988 of 12848
2989 of 12848
2990 of 12848
2991 of 12848
2992 of 12848
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_extraction\extract_data.py", line 68, in <module>
    data = extract_data(yesterday,days = 1)
  File "db_extraction\extract_data.py", line 24, in extract_data
    for i,d in enumerate(table.find({'timestamp': {'$gte': start, '$lte':end}}).limit(100000)):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1169, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1106, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(g)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 971, in __send_message
    codec_options=self.__codec_options)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1055, in _unpack_response
    return response.unpack_response(cursor_id, codec_options)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 945, in unpack_response
    return bson.decode_all(self.documents, codec_options)
bson.errors.InvalidBSON
```

First thing I've tried is changing the range of the query to check if it is data related, and it's not. Another range stops at 1615 of 6360 and same error.

I've also tried `list(table.find({'timestamp': {'$gte': start, '$lte':end}})` and same error.

Another maybe relevant info is that first queries are really fast. It freezes on the last number for a while before returning the error.

So I need some help. Am I hitting limits here? Or any clue on whats going on?

This is might be related with [this 2013 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685492/pymongo-cursor-not-looping), but the author says that he gets no error output.

Thanks!

EDIT:

First thank you all for your time and suggestions. Unfortunately, I've tested all sugestions and I get the same error at the same spot. I've printed the problematic file using mongo shell and it is pretty much the same as all others. 
I changed the range of the query and tried picking up other days. Same problem in all days, until I found one random run that gave me a MEMORY ERROR.

```
1737 of 8011
1738 of 8011
1739 of 8011
1740 of 8011
1741 of 8011
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_extraction\pymongo_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    for post in all_posts:
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1189, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1126, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(g)
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 931, in __send_message
    operation, exhaust=self.__exhaust, address=self.__address)
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1145, in _send_message_with_response
    exhaust)
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1156, in _reset_on_error
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 106, in send_message_with_response
    reply = sock_info.receive_message(request_id)
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 612, in receive_message
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 745, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise error
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 610, in receive_message
    self.max_message_size)
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 191, in receive_message
    data = _receive_data_on_socket(sock, length - 16)
  File "\python_modules\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 227, in _receive_data_on_socket
    buf = bytearray(length)
MemoryError
```

This is intermitent. I ran again without changing anything and got the old invalidBSON error, and ran again and got Memory Error.

I started the task manager and ran again, and the memory indeed grows fast up to 95% usage and hangs there. The query should retrieve something like 1GB of data in 8GB RAM machine so... I dont know if this is suposed to happen. Anyway a code suggestion that retrieves the data from mongoDB with pymongo and writes to a file without putting everything into memory probably will do the job. The bonus would be if someone could explain why I'm getting an invalid BSON instead of MemoryError (for vast majority of runs) in my case.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314776/pymongo-error-bson-errors-invalidbson-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa1-in-p

Comment: I also saw this questions but thought it was unrelated. After your comment I've tried setting unicode_decode_error_handler='ignore'  and tried downgrading to pymongo2.8. Neither made any difference and I get the problem on the exact same spot of the loop. Difference with pymongo2.8 is that it hangs indefinitely and returns no error.

Comment: If you tried retrieving fewer documents say 1000 documents per time, do you have the same errors?

Comment: Fewer than 2900 Just works as expected. I used a workaround using subprocess and mongodump with the query flag for my application and this also works. So It is something related to pymongo.

Comment: What happens if you just do : `for doc in collection.find({'timestamp': {'$gte': start, '$lte':end}}): print(doc)` ? do you still get the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine on my computer. Since it works for your first 2992 records, I think the documents may have some inconsistency. Does every document in your collection follow the same schema and format? and is your pymongo updated?

Here is my suggestion if you want to loop through every record:

```
data = []
all_posts = db.my_collection.find({'timestamp': {'$gte': start, '$lte':end}})
tam = all_posts.count()
i = 0
for post in all_posts:
    i += 1
    print('%s of %s' % (i,tam))
    data.append(post)
```

Regards,

Comment: by the way my test collection size is 73000

Comment: I have tried upgrading and downgrading pymongo a few times. My DB is 80GB, and this problem happens in different ranges of queries. Schema is always fixed in the range of the query. Also, dumping and restoring works with mongodump and mongorestore. I really need here something out of the box. Something related to my operational system (Windows 10 Home unfortunatelly) or that this happens because of some indexing I've done, or some configuration of mongo server or...  I dont know. Your code is pretty much the same as mine and have the same problem in my enviroment. BTW I'm running pymongo 3.7.1

Comment: From the [official `InvalidBSON` documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/1.7/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.InvalidBSON) I second the hunch that the documents might have inconsistencies. Have you tried to take a look at the documents for which you receive the error @Alex?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same exact problem myself, it ended up having nothing to do with the documents themselves but the amount of memory that the program was taking up during large queries.

In our specific case, when running the broken query that was giving us this exact bug by itself in a separate script, the bug didn't occur. Eventually we found that we were using a uwsgi config setting:

```
limit-as = 512
```

This would immediately kill our process when address space reached 512M, resulting in either an InvalidBSON error OR a MemoryError interchangeably, seemingly at random.

We fixed this by changing the limit-as setting it to reload-on-as instead:

```
reload-on-as = 512
```

Ultimately we ended up with deciding to break up large queries like this into smaller pieces and performing them sequentially instead of all at once anyway, but we at least determined it was an external cause instead of an issue with the pymongo driver itself.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to specific documents in the DB? Have you checked the document that might cause the error (e.g., the 2992th result of your above query, starting with 0)?

You could also execute some queries against the DB directly (e.g., via [the `mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/)) without using pymongo to see whether expected results are returned. For example, you could try `db.my_collection.find({...}).skip(2992)` to see the result. You could also use [`cursor.forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) to print all the retrieved documents.